# How do to pagination in Sanic?

Tags: pagination, sanic

I tried to get the request arguments and wanted to use pagination in sanic. It is sanic motor. Have used mongodb to find the details. i want to use limit and skip.

```
@app.route("/query", methods=["GET"])
async def query_params(request, count=10, page=1):
    a = request.args
    count = request.args['count'][0]
    page = a.get('page')
    students = await Student.find(as_raw=True).skip((page-1) * count).limit(count)
    return json_response(students.objects)
```

It gives error  AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'skip' while handling path /query
Same for limit i get this error

Answer (score 0):

This is not really Sanic related. I think the problem is your await is being applied to the whole chain and not what you think. If you use some parentheses you can control it  as below.

Note: I'm not familiar with the ORM so I'm not sure if skip and limit also need awaits or not.

students = await (Student.find(as_raw=True)).skip((page-1) * count).limit(count)